# Excel hyperlink - update cell automatically

Tags: excel

I have a problem finding (if exist) a method to update the hyperlink values automatically.

Example: I have 2 Spreadsheets: Document and List. In Document i have a hyperlinks which connects to A20 from List. If adding before the cell A20 two new rows, i will need to manually modify the hyperlink (Edit hyperlink of CTRL+K) to change the hyperlink from Document to A22. 
This process can be made automatically when adding or erase rows in the spreadsheet List?

Comment: What data you have in cell A20? And what is the syntax you are using for Hyperlink?

Comment: For the hyperlink is used a normal hyperlink [Excel windows: cell - 'CTRL+K' - Place in This Document - Type the cell reference (A20) - Cell Reference (List).] The above information is an example. I have multiple Sheet. And the first sheet will reference to a cell from the other sheet using the hyperlink. And the problem appears because i need to add new rows in the spreadsheets and this will cause the hyperlink to reference to a wrong location (the cell reference remain the same, and i need to modify them manual.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use hyperlink, just update the file paths. I just used a match formula to look for "Link Here" in the List file and it worked for me.

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\List.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$"&MATCH("Link here",'C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\[List.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1:$A1000,0),"Link to List")
```